# Targetting HTTP Error Messages

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I'm trying to send an JSON-encoded data string to a remote machine using AJAX.
Whenever I try to send the data string to the remote machine, one of two error messages will occur:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.1.0.139:8000/. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on 
the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

This message occurs when the remote machine is powered on and accepting connections. However, although I am getting this error, my code is working exactly as I want it to - as in, the remote machine receives the correct piece of data.

```
POST http://10.1.0.139:8000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And this message occurs when the remote machine is either powered off or does not have it's own server running that accepts incoming requests and connections.

The problem is, I want to be able to differentiate between these two error messages, and I do not know how. I can't use AJAX callbacks such as error() or fail(), because there will always be an error - and it will say that there has been a failed request despite a HTTP status of 200 suggesting that everything is okay (when the first error message shows).

### Is there a way that I can do something similar to a Pseudo command of 'IF I FAIL TO CONNECT TO REMOTE MACHINE, DO...'

*EDIT*

*Something I've noticed just now is that my remote machine does not display incoming connections from Internet Explorer - instead it displays this:*

```
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd,   
Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.
```

Comment: add CORS responses to the server at :8000 ... then you'll be able to read any response sent by the server at :8000

Comment: alternatively, XMLHttpRequest does have a `timeout` setting and a `timeout` event ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the XMLHttpRequest timeout

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
var data = 'x=1';
xhr.open('POST', 'http://10.1.0.139:8000/');
xhr.timeout = 5000;
xhr.addEventListener('timeout', function(e) {
   // handle dead server 
   console.log('timeout');
   console.error(e);
});
xhr.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
   // handle error - CORS probably in this case
   console.log('error');
   console.error(e);
});
xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
   // handle success
   console.log('load');
   console.info(e);
});
xhr.send(data);
```

This triggers `error` in the case of a CORS error, and `timeout` in the case of no server

Comment: I don't think a timeout approach will work, because typically within a few seconds it will report back saying "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: really? which browser (and what version of it) does that?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 and yeah the only thing being triggered is the `error`

Comment: weird - I seem to recall that being something to do with an ad blocker or some such? read it on SO, so it must be true :p